# Netstream() progressive download of internal file

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

Hello All I have been working on a project for a while:

I have a `non standard MP4 video file` I want to `play off a server in a IPhone App` (I am using `Flash builder` to create it).

Due to a combination of server problems (not correctly identifying `MIME` type and cant be changed) and `IPhone` limitations (e.g. not being able to force the `iplayer` to play files with wrong extension), I have had to setup a process that reads the file in, saves it locally and then point the video player at the local file.

Although this sort of works, i am `having an issue` with some of the `files that are large` `(94mb for a 17 min video)` and a `slow server` - which takes 120 seconds to transfer the whole file.

I thought that if you started playing the video, then the transfer rate would be faster than the playback rate so the video would play ok.

However sometimes the video just crashes, which i am guessing is a result of the video reading beyond what has been written.

If the video played the internal file using progressive download I think it would probably not crash but resume once more date had been read but understand that progressive download is triggered by a `url` extension beginning with `HTTP://`

Can you make an internal file play using `progressive download` ? I know this would not normally be expected as logically the system would expect a local file to already be download ?
Any help appreciated 
Thanks
Toby

Comment: Basically, what you are doing is hacking a work-around for something else that is broken. I think you need to step back and take another look at why the server has an issue with the mime type. Fix the server if you can  or if the issue is with the mp4 then try reencoding it.

Comment: Thanks but neither possibe - the server is embeded into a camera so you cant add a mime type to it and the videos are generated automatically by the camera so cant change the encoding / name of files

Answer (score 0):

try this to know download file is complete or not

[HCDownload](https://github.com/H2CO3/HCDownload)

it is very easy to use only write its delegate method.

**Edit**

also see [StitchedStreamPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Samir, i can work out if the file is downloaded already. However need to start playback before downlaod has completed as this could take 2 mins. I really need a way of controlling the internal file so i doesnt try to read past what has already been written.

Comment: i think you want to stream the video. not download. see my edited answer